# ¿Cómo puedo hacer POST hacia una url remota utilizando Express?

Tags: javascript, express, post, postman, body

Muy buenas a todos,
me encuentro en un problema, no llevo mucho tiempo utilizando js en el lado del servidor y quisiera una ayuda en este problema.

En pocas palabras, necesito hacer POST hacia una url externa pasándole una entrada **en este formato**:

{"string" : "palabra1 palabra2 palabra3 palabra4 palabra3 palabra1 palabra3 palabra2"}

Puede ser cualquier frase mientras estén separadas por un espacio.

Al utilizar **POSTMAN** puedo hacerlo sin problemas, definiendo esta entrada en la sección **RAW** de la pestaña **BODY** como ilustra la siguiente captura de pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi punto es, como puedo hacer exactamente eso, pero desde Express en JavaScript.

Cuento con lo siguiente en el servidor:

**index.js**

```html
const port = require('./config/config').port;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(require('cors')());
app.use(require('body-parser').json());

app.use('/elLink', require('./api/Controllers/elControlador'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}...`));
```

**elControlador.js**

```html
const servicio = require('../../Data/service');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await servicio.funcion();
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json(e.message);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**service.js**

```html
const { funcion_2 } = require('./repository');

async function funcion() {
    return await funcion_2();
}

module.exports = {
    funcion
}
```

**repository.js**

```html
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function funcion_2() {
    const url='https://fe...';
    const data=await (await fetch(url)).text();
    return data;
}
module.exports = {
    funcion_2
};
```

**El link al que quiero hacer post está en repository.js como https://fe...**

No se en donde definir la entrada. ni como pasarla por "parámetro" o algo por el estilo, aclaro que esta url no acepta algo como: "elLink/laentradaenlaurl", debe ser explícitamente como lo hace en POSTMAN, pasándole la entrada en formato raw en el body.

Agradezco de antemano si alguien puede ayudarme, es de suma importancia para mi proyecto.

Comment: Postman tiene una utilidad que te permite crear la consulta con fetch tal como la haces con la herramienta gráfica. Usa esa utilidad  para que veas como la realiza Postman y puedas implementarla en tu código. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias, está solucionado, no creí que fuera algo tan simple. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de @MauricioContreras pude solucionar la duda que tenía.
La función de repository.js quedó de la siguiente forma

```html
var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var raw = JSON.stringify({"string":"entrada de ejemplo"});

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    return fetch("elLinkAlQueEnvioElPost", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```