# ¿Cómo puedo hacer POST en express (Node.js) y subir a una base de datos los resultados usando el navegador?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, express, post

Estoy aprendiendo Node.js, y me he quedado atascado en un punto. He creado una API con Node.js, Express y MySQL. La API recupera los datos que se encuentran en una tabla en una base de datos. La tabla, en este caso, solo recoge dos valores: "name" y "city".

En Postman soy capaz de recuperar los datos de esa base de datos, e incluso de insertar valores, actualizarlos o borrarlos. Pero cuando lo hago desde el navegador, solo soy capaz de hacer GET (no puedo hacer POST para subir valores). En Postman, envío datos a la base de datos usando el método POST, y luego yendo a Body, marcar raw, y ahí inserto los nuevos valores en formato JSON.

He revisado en este foro y me he encontrado, por ejemplo, con [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451912/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-post-hacia-una-url-remota-utilizando-express) que parece la adecuada. He sido capaz de encontrar ese código en Postman, pero no entiendo dónde ponerlo.

Este es el código que funciona cuando uso Postman:

```js
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';

  const customerObj = {
    name: req.body.name,
    city: req.body.city
  };

  connection.query(sql, customerObj, error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send('Customer created!');
  });
});
```

Y esto es lo que me recomienda Postman que use:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "name": "Marco",
  "city": "Polo"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://tupi-nodejs-test.herokuapp.com/add", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Ojalá podáis ayudarme a entender dónde debo poner ese código, es muy importante para mí poder resolver esto.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar ajax para  pasar los datos del navegador tal que así:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/add",
                    data: `name=${$('.xxx').val()}&city=123`,
                    success: function (res) {
                        console.log(res)
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Desafortunadamente mi problema es el mismo, ¿cómo puedo usar eso para enviar los datos a la bd? ¿Debería sustituir el console.log(res) por la función `connection.query(sql, customerObj, error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send('Customer created!');
  });`?

Comment: para insertar en la base de datos usando mysql, sigue estos pasos:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

ahí te viene para conectarte contra la base de datos y como hacer un insert y demás

Comment: Entonces, si lo he entendido bien, ¿no necesito hacer el POST para subir los datos a la base de datos? ¿Sólo con el connection.query sería suficiente? Discúlpame por favor, recién he empezado con Node.JS

Comment: sin problema, si quieres pasar datos desde la web a la base de datos, necesitas hacer el post y dentro del post poner la sentencia sql tal que así:
app.post('/prueba', async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const nombre = body.nombre;
    const ciudad = body.ciudad;
    const con = mysql.createConnection(config);
    await con.query(
        "call procedimiento_de_prueba(?)",
        [nombre, ciudad],
        function (err, result) {
            let resQuery = result[0];
            con.end();
            return res.json(1);
        }
    );
});

Comment: Perdona que regrese otra vez a lo mismo, pero, ¿cómo consigo hacer el POST? El navegador sólo me deja hacer GET, y no entiendo de AJAX. Entiendo que para hacer POST debo usar lo que Postman me sugiere, pero no entiendo dónde.

Comment: para hacer la llamada por get pon /miRuta/:name/:city

y accedes con req.params.name y req.params.city, la url será algo tal que así:

localhost:PORT/miRuta/nombre1/ciudad1

Comment: y para usar ajax, en un archivo .html o .hbs o lo que uses, tienes que poner la función que te pasé antes, en una etiqueta <script></script>

Comment: Debería ser así, entonces, ¿no? `app.get('/add/:name/:city', (req, res) => {
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';

  const customerObj = {
    name: req.params.name,
    city: req.params.city
  };

  connection.query(sql, customerObj, error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send('Customer created!');
  });
});`

Comment: creo que sí, si no mira la guia de mysql que te pasé antes en npm

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias entonces. Lo probé y sigue sin funcionar, volveré a revisar la guía de npm porque no entiendo nada. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: pero que error te da???

Comment: Me da el error `Cannot GET /customers/add/Pepito/Uruguay` cuando intento esa ruta

Comment: entonces en tu get tienes que poner /customers/add/:nombre/:ciudad

Comment: te falta el /customers antes del /add y entra en la url con localhost:PORT/customers/add/nombre/ciudad

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ese era mi problema entonces. Para resumir, ¿no es posible usar POST/PUT/DELETE por Node.JS desde la web sino que debo hacerlo todo mediante GET?

Comment: para usar POST, PUT o DELETE, tienes que usarlo desde un navegador, quiero decir, en tu archivo .html o .hbs donde tienes tu código html, tienes que tener un <script></script> donde tengas una función ajax para mandarle al servidor en node las cosas por POST, PUT o DELETE, dentro de method: 'POST' es donde pones de que forma se lo quieres pasar, pero tienes que hacerlo dentro de un ficher html o de un javascript en el frontend

Comment: con ajax evitas que se recargue la página cada vez que llamas al servidor

Comment: Todo claro entonces, creo que de momento seguiré usando GET. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: sin problema, al principio cuesta un poco pero luego es mas fácil